# About a type specifier in NuSMV (error: invalid subrange)

Tags: static-analysis, model-checking

In the last paragraph, page # 23 of user manual 2.5 (I am using 2.5.4):

> "A type specifier can be given by two expressions separated by .. (<TWO 
>   DOTS>).
>   The two expressions have both to evaluate to constants integer numbers, and 
>   may
>   contain names of defines and module formal parameters. For example, -1 - P1 ..
>   5 + D1, where P1 refers to a module formal parameter, and D1 refers to a
>   define. Both P1 and D1 have to be statically evaluable to integer constants."

I have tested many different examples to run something like it but I couldn't
finally. This is one of them:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    third_party : third_party;
    alice : alice(third_party.n); 

MODULE third_party
FROZENVAR
    p : 0..1000;
    q : 0..1000;
DEFINE 
    n := p * q;

MODULE alice(n)
FROZENVAR
    r :  1 .. n;
```

or something like this:

```
MODULE main
FROZENVAR
        p : 0..1000;
        q : 0..1000;
VAR
alice : alice(n);
    DEFINE 
        n := p * q;
MODULE alice(n)
    FROZENVAR
        r :  1 .. n;
```

The error is "invalid subrange 1 .. n"

Can anybody help me? Can you give me examples that type specifier contain names of defines and module formal parameters and run correctly?

Indeed this code is part of fiat-shamir protocol, and I am testing a ctl on different values of n (n cannot be a constant integer), and looking for a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `third_party.n` is not statically evaluable. It depends on the values of `third_party.p` and `third_party.q`, which are both variable. Therefore, the module is not instantiated with a statically evaluable expression.

An example that may work is:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    third_party : third_party;
    alice : alice(third_party.n); 

MODULE third_party
FROZENVAR
    p : 0..1000;
    q : 0..1000;
DEFINE 
    n := 10 * 10;

MODULE alice(n)
FROZENVAR
    r :  1 .. n;
```

Comment: thanks.this example works correctly but I need to do first one or sth like this: MODULE main VAR   p : 0..1000; q : 0 : 1000; DEFINE n := p * q;  VAR  r : 1..n;  s : 1 .. n;                                                                                                                                 do you have any idea to do this job or the first one?                                  this code is part of a protocol(fiat-shamir) and parameter n cannot be a constant integer,  I am testing a ctl on this protocol on different values of n, and I want to find a counterexample...thank you so much

Comment: It is not possible to check a property for all n in one go, because this n influences the size of the model. I think that the only solution is to generate a model for every n (by hand or with a program) and then check each of them using NuSMV.

Comment: thank you thomas... but I think that it is impossible to check by hand because p and q are large integers.and also one of the most important facilities of model-checking is to check every possible value to find a counter-example for a ctl or ltl...I'm confused...I couldn't find  a similar protocol that is modeled by NuSMV in internet...have you model a protocol by musmv?

Comment: I have not modeled a protocol in NuSMV, just some simple railroad systems and single player puzzles. Yes, model checking is about checking all possible executions, but most often not about checking some property for all model parameters. There are some tools that can do parametric model checking (PARAM for example). If you want to prove this algorithm unsafe, then it might be easier to write a mathematical proof.